# How to get the data using find_by Or where in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Truck 
  id: 1,
  vehicle_registration_number: "TN38CC6077",
  chassis_number: "12345",
  created_at: "2016-09-06 05:39:19",
  updated_at: "2016-09-06 05:39:19",
  company_truck_type_id: 1,
  location_id: 492,
  available_date: ["2016-09-10",
  "2016-09-20"],
  booked_status: "Available",
  active: true,
  manager_id: 3,
  loading_supervisor_id: 3,
  transport_supervisor_id: 3,
  user_id: 3,
  status: "just_in",
  price: #<BigDecimal:afae0204,'0.109E5',9(18)>, 
  source_id: 492, 
  destination_id: 3, 
  notes: ["HelloWorld"]
```

This is my data in a table. From Here I have use `available_date` to find a current data,but it can't working. How can I get based on current date?

```
@truck[0].where(available_date:["2016-09-10"]["2016-09-20"])
```

It's not working. I want to check if the `current date` is between the `available_date` or not?

Comment: Is that column of `array` type or is that a serialized array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like below:

```
Truck.where(available_date: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I want to check today's date is between available date if it true get the data to one variable...........

Comment: truck = Truck.where(available_date: (Date.today - 1)..Date.today)

Comment: So that means you are checking available_date between yesterday to today that is current date.

Comment: Ok if i want to check the available_date is greater than or equals to today's date means what will do? Bcoz My date format is 
(available_date:["2016-09-10","2016-09-20"]) in a db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippets ;

```
def current_date_is_available?(available_date)
 current_date = Date.parse(Time.now.to_s)
 Date.parse(available_date.first) < current_date && current_date < Date.parse(available_date.second)
end
```

in controller ;

```
if current_date_is_available?(@truck[0].available_date)
    # do whatever you want
end
```

Comment: Column is String with Array element storage, like this in db
t.string   "available_date",  array: true

Comment: try to parse the available_date before passing to method like this `JSON.parse(@truck[0].available_date)`